# zsh can't input to terminal when piping stdin and stdout with variable command that has tty output

Tags: bash, zsh, pipe, tty

System info:

```
macOS Sierra 10.12.6
zsh 5.4.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0)
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16.3.0)
```

Scroll to the **EXAMPLES** at the bottom if you just want to dig in to the simplified examples that I made.

NOTE: I am not a big `zsh` user.

---

I was looking at the [`fzf`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) keybindings for [`bash`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/shell/key-bindings.bash#L59) and [`zsh`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/shell/key-bindings.zsh#L73).

Notice how they both run a variable command `$(__fzfcmd)`. `__fzfcmd` by default outputs `fzf` to stdout and the parameter substitution just runs command (`fzf`) resulting from the output.

One difference between the `bash` and `zsh` script is that the `bash` one further pipes the output of `$(__fzfcmd)` but `zsh` just captures it inside an array. My guess is because of a problem in `zsh` when you further pipe the output of `fzf` where you can't input to `fzf` and the process piped to by `fzf` doesn't get any stdin. Your only choice is to `^Z` or `^C`. `^C` seems to background the process for some reason. Or maybe they just wanted it in an array so they could could [run `zle vi-fetch-history` on it](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/shell/key-bindings.zsh#L78). The `bash` version does some magic in the key binding with [`"\e^": history-expand-line`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/shell/key-bindings.bash#L83)

Now `fzf` isn't important. It seems like you just need a program that outputs to the `tty` to be called by parameter substitution to cause this problem. So I will show some simpler examples.

Here are some other commands that output to the `tty` that can cause this problem in `zsh`:

- [vipe](https://linux.die.net/man/1/vipe) (run editor in middle of a pipe)
- `'vim -'` (make vim read from stdin. similar to vipe but won't output to stdout)

---

In the examples below, replace every occurrence of `vipe` with `vim -` if you don't want to do a separate install. Just remember that `vim -` won't output the editor contents to stdout like `vipe` does.

**EXAMPLES:**

```
1) echo 1 | vipe | cat            # works in both bash and zsh
2) echo 1 | $(echo vipe) | cat    # works in bash only. zsh problem with no output until I hit `^C`:
   ^C
   zsh: done                    echo 1 | 
   zsh: suspended (tty output)  $(echo vipe) | 
   zsh: interrupt               cat
   # seems like the process is backgrounded. I can still see it in jobs command

3) cat <(echo 1 | $(echo vipe))   # zsh and bash has the problem. I'm guessing because
                                  # the file isn't finished writing and cat is
                                  # blocking vipe's tty output
                                  # both their `^C` output is just:
   ^C # nothing special, as expected

4) cat < <(echo 1 | $(echo vipe)) # works in both bash and zsh
5) echo 1 | $(echo vipe) > >(cat) # works in both bash and zsh

# The following don't have and input pipe to vipe.
# Type something then send EOF with ^D
6) vipe | cat                     # works for both
7) $(echo vipe) | cat             # works for both
```

Now, I'm mostly wondering why `2)` has a problem for `zsh` but not for `bash` and why `4)` and `5)` fixes the problem for `zsh`.

The requirements for `zsh` to have this problem to seem to be exactly what I put in the title:

- input pipe
- command run by variable/parameter substitution that has `tty` output
- output pipe

**UPDATE**

I added another workaround that doesn't cause `zsh` to have this problem, `5)`. It's similar to `4)` but instead of redirecting `stdout` directly into `stin`, I redirect it into a file that redirects into `stdin` using process substitution.

Comment: As the output of `ps` will tell you, in _none_ of these cases are the shells frozen or stuck.  They are simply waiting for child processes in the normal way; and they will indeed loop back to prompting for input in the normal way once those child processes are suspended or terminated.  Your question title and body include an implicit false premise.  "Why does my shell freeze?" is an unanswerable loaded question when your shell is _not_ actually freezing in the first place.  You would have a better question for removing this implicit false premise.

Comment: Ok, I can change it. It's not really frozen in the sense that the process isn't able to run instructions on the CPU anymore. You are correct that it is just waiting. But is it not 'stuck'? It's waiting for input I am not able to provide it. What's a better term to describe this concisely?
Does it not match this description of [hang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hang_(computing))

`when either a computer program or system ceases to respond to inputs`

Comment: The shell is not waiting for input.  It is waiting for its children.  This question would be better put _simply describing what happens_.  Don't form hypotheses and inferences such as "my shell is frozen" and then ask about the inferences.  Describe what happens and ask about that: _The special character terminal input sequences_ (that would normally suspend the foreground job, or interrupt or quit the job, or send an EOF indication to the process reading from the terminal) _have no effect. What is happening? Why?_.  This is replicatable on Debian Linux and FreeBSD/TrueOS, by the way,

Comment: The shell is waiting on the `cat` command. The `cat` is waiting for it's children. Isn't one of it's children waiting for input? vipe normally shows the vim interface to the command line. Then you can edit the text and do `:q` to quit. That would normally, output to stdout and `cat` would stop waiting and then the shell would stop waiting. But because I can't input to `vipe`, `cat` is left waiting and then the `shell` is left waiting. All this because `vipe` can't get input. So in effect it is waiting for input?

Comment: The special characters do work. I can `^Z` and `^C`. `EOF` (`^D`) doesn't make sense in this case because everything is piped so nothing would see that `EOF`.
I need something short and descriptive in the title and the code examples.
Thanks for reproducing on the other OSs.

Comment: Okay, I changed some things around. I described the problem and then referenced it by 'the problem' to avoid repeating it. I also removed the 'freeze' tag. Let me know I can improve on it more. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I've [reported the bug on the zsh development mailing list](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2018/msg00318.html). For now, you should be able to work around it by wrapping it in a subshell `(echo | $(echo vipe) | cat)`

Comment: The fact that process substitutions are started in background is documented I think (or at least known)

Comment: Similar bug: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585941/zsh-bug-unexpected-process-suspension

Comment: Since this bug has been reported and nothing that anyone can do about it here, can this question be closed?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue boils down to improperly quoting your expansions.

Quoting from [zsh:14 Expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html)

> A command enclosed in parentheses preceded by a dollar sign, like
>   `$(...)`, or quoted with grave accents, like ‘`...`’, is replaced with
>   its standard output, with any trailing newlines deleted. If the
>   substitution is not enclosed in double quotes, the output is broken
>   into words using the IFS parameter. The substitution `$(cat foo)` may
>   be replaced by the equivalent but faster `$(<foo)`. In either case, if
>   the option GLOB_SUBST is set, the output is eligible for filename
>   generation.

Note that Example #2 in your question results in an infinite echo of NULL, due to:

> If the substitution is not enclosed in double quotes, the output is
>   broken into words using the IFS parameter.

In other words the shell infinitely waits for the `echo`, because the default delimiter is SPACE, the echo never completes.  [See TLDP: Internal Variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html).  This leaves a hung pipe for the `cat` command.

As a hunch, I believe 4 and 5 work due to output redirection.