# zsh bug: Unexpected process suspension

Tags: zsh, pipe, io-redirection, stdin, job-control

Update: simpler reproduction

```
mdoc-test () {
    sleep 0 | sleep 0
    cat
}

echo start |VISUAL=vim command vipe|mdoc-test
# zsh: suspended (tty output)
```

[Posted](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2020/msg00638.html) to zsh mailing list.

---

```
mdoc-test () {
  echo echo hi | {
                eval "$(cat -)"
        }
  echo "input from fzf: $(cat -)" # this line is not needed to reproduce the problem, it's just here for ... aesthetics.
}

echo a |command fzf|mdoc-test
```

Fails with (`fzf` doesn't open at all):

```
hi
  ok
    [1]  + 65356 done                   echo a |


    65357 suspended (tty input)  command fzf
```

This same code works flawlessly in bash.

Update: `setopt nomultios` doesn't solve this issue either.

Comment: What is `mdoc-test` doing with the input coming from `fzf`? (rhetorical question)

Comment: @Kusalananda It's a completely madeup thing to reproduce easily. My actual code is rather complicated. I use fzf to reorder and filter some links I want to download, and then use a function that has a line similar to mdoc-test in it to further process the links.

Comment: But `mdoc-test` doesn't even read the output from `fzf`. That `cat -` in there is reading the string `echo hi`.

Comment: @Kusalananda `mdoc-test` is just a toy example and I have coded it as the simplest possible function that reproduces the problem. The real function does read the input from fzf as well. I'll update `mdoc-test` now to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Possibly same as [zsh can't input to terminal when piping stdin and stdout with variable command that has tty output](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/411688). See https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2018/msg00318.html

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I simplified the bug reproduction based on that thread. They are similar bugs, but possibly different.

Comment: Since this is [confirmed to be a bug in Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2020/msg00640.html), can this question be closed?

Comment: @MarlonRichert The bug has not gotten fixed though, has it? Idk. Whatever the mods want.

Comment: Well, no one here can help you with it, right? And this is not the place to report Zsh bugs.